# How to make complicated replacement of values in string column using dictionary?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe, function

I have a dictionary in pandas dataframe form:

```
name     value 
phil      1
andy      4
allen     5
```

and a table which looks like this:

```
phil/andy    
allen
```

I want to replace values in it by value from first table:

```
1/4    
5
```

how to do that?

Comment: If this is related to pandas please add the pandas tag

Comment: Is it guaranteed that names are separated by something? what happens if you also have a name allena with number 6?

Comment: @NiteyaShah each name has unique value in first dataframe. and yes, if there are more than 1 names in second dataframe, they are separate by /

Answer (score 0):

Data:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'name': {0: 'phil', 1: 'andy', 2: 'allen'},
                   'value': {0: 1, 1: 4, 2: 5}})

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'names': {0: 'phil/andy', 1: 'allen'}})
```

Code

```
d = dict(zip(df['name'], df['value'].astype(str)))    
df1['replaced'] = df1['names'].str.replace("\\w+", lambda x:d.get(x[0]), regex=True)

df1
      names replaced
0  phil/andy      1/4
1      allen        5
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way to do what your question asks:

```py
def foo(x):
    df['some_column'] = df['some_column'].str.replace(str(x['name']), str(x['value']))

dfNames.apply(foo, axis=1)
```

Sample input:

```
    name  value
0   phil      1
1   andy      4
2  allen      5

  some_column
0   phil/andy
1       allen
```

Sample output:

```
  some_column
0         1/4
1           5
```

Comment: @gh1222 Do you need more help with this question?